# WSGI handler "app" could not be imported (Flask)

Tags: flask, wsgi

i have a question about WSGI handler.

I worked on my laptop with my flask app and the IIS, the web app works good and it's displayed on the browser.

Now i'm configured the app on a server, but now i have a error when i call the web app

there's some additional  steps i have to do on a server?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyWebSite\wfastcgi.py", line 711, in main
    env, handler = read_wsgi_handler(response.physical_path)
  File "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyWebSite\wfastcgi.py", line 568, in read_wsgi_handler
    return env, get_wsgi_handler(handler_name)
  File "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyWebSite\wfastcgi.py", line 551, in get_wsgi_handler
    raise ValueError('"%s" could not be imported' % handler_name)
ValueError: "runserver.app" could not be imported
```

i think i missing something,

my runserver.py (app) had a simple call

```
from os import environ

from QPX_Test import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

i should have to create a .wsgi file? or there's another configuration?

thanks in advance

Comment: I had the same issue. Make sure you have installed all the modules including Flask in server too.

Comment: i will try, what about to give "run administrator" feature when i use python interaction

Answer (score 0):

According to my experience this error arises due to any malfunctioned import statement in your runserver.py , it can be any other script that your're importing. In your case , try replacing 
`from QPX_Test import app`

with

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
```